# How should I use terraform in multi pods?

Tags: terraform

My needs are：

1. Distributed `web/RPC` server, deployed on several pods
2. the service is used to control the terraform cli, modifying environment variables or `.tf` files in order to Dynamic creation/destruction of resources

To keep the state consistent, I'm using etcd v3 as a backend to the terraform, now the question is.

1. inconsistent `.tf` files on different pods, which can lead to confusion of resources

> What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I used etcd v3 as backend to sync the tf_state in each pod.